# Spring data elasticsearch mapping

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm new to working with Elasticsearch mappings, I've created my class Bordereau with annotation inside the class and a json file which contains the mapping.

```
@Document(indexName = "#{@profilePrefixe}_bordereau", type = "Bordereau")
@Mapping(mappingPath = "/mapping/bordereau-mapping.json")
public class BordereauOe {
    @Id
    private String idBordereau;
    @Field(type= FieldType.Keyword)
    private String numBordereau;
    private String idCreateur;
    private int existe;
    private String dateCreation;
    private Long dateCreationMiliseconde;
    private int nbrDossier;
    private int nbrDossierTraiter;
    private boolean statut;
    private boolean statutSaturatoin;
    private String bordereauFile;
    @Field(type= FieldType.Keyword)
    private String nomClient;
    private int nbrDossierAffecter;
    private String cabinet;
    @Field(type= FieldType.Keyword)
    private String compagnie;
    private int nbrDossierAjoutes;
```

with the following mapping file : bordereau-mapping.json

```
{

  "Bordereau" : {
    "properties" : {
      "accusedFiles" : {
        "type" : "text"
      },
      "bordereauFile" : {
        "type" : "text"
      },
      "cabinet" : {
        "type" : "keyword"
      },
      "compagnie" : {
        "type" : "keyword"
      },
      "dateCreation" : {
        "type" : "date",
        "format" : "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy/MM/dd"
      },
      "dateCreationMiliseconde" : {
        "type" : "long"
      },
      "existe" : {
        "type" : "long"
      },
      "idBordereau" : {
        "type" : "text"
      },
      "idCreateur" : {
        "type" : "text"
      },
      "nbrDossier" : {
        "type" : "long"
      },
      "nbrDossierAffecter" : {
        "type" : "long"
      },
      "nbrDossierAjoutes" : {
        "type" : "long"
      },
      "nbrDossierTraiter" : {
        "type" : "long"
      },
      "nomClient" : {
        "type" : "keyword"
      },
      "numBordereau" : {
        "type" : "keyword"
      },
      "statut" : {
        "type" : "boolean"
      },
      "statutSaturatoin" : {
        "type" : "boolean"
      }
    }
  }
```

}

That project is (still) working fine.
but after a day, it throw the flowing exceptions

> [ERROR] 2018-08-24 08:31:24.859 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] AcquisitionLogs:56 - ******* Exception :   org.springframework.data.mapping.context.InvalidPersistentPropertyPath: No property 'dateCreation' found on class ma.accolade.ged.ms.gestion.acquisition.persistance.oe.BordereauOe! Did you mean: dateCreation?
>       [ERROR] 2018-08-24 09:35:04.429 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] AcquisitionLogs:56 - ******* Exception : org.springframework.data.mapping.context.InvalidPersistentPropertyPath: No property 'idUser' found on class ma.accolade.ged.ms.gestion.acquisition.persistance.oe.PreferenceAffichageOe! Did you mean: idUser?
>       [ERROR] 2018-08-24 09:36:04.537 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] AcquisitionLogs:56 - ******* Exception : org.springframework.data.mapping.context.InvalidPersistentPropertyPath: No property 'id' found on class ma.accolade.ged.ms.gestion.acquisition.persistance.oe.DocumentOe! Did you mean: id?

Thanks again in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong type definitions in class vs mapping. for eg:

```
public class BordereauOe {
   private String dateCreation;
}

and in mapping, you have it defined as Date

"dateCreation" : {
    "type" : "date",
    "format" : "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy/MM/dd"
  }
```

please go through all the field definitions between class and mapping and make sure it matches

Comment: thanks for ur ansswer 
and if I have a field in my class with type  List<String> how can I mapped it

Comment: here is the documentation for array type https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-array-type.html please select the version that you're using